# resetting a HttpRequest after calling request.getReader()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httprequest

Is there a way to call the `getReader()` method on a `HttpRequest` and then "reset" the request so other calls to `getReader()` will not throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException`?

Comment: I'm confused by this question. The API does not allow getInputStream and getReader to be called on the same request. Do you want to avoid this scenario ? Or are you attempting to get multiple readers on the same request object?

Comment: @Vineet I am trying to extract the request body and log it, and then pass the request to the next handlers (in my case spring components) and let them work as usual. I want to avoid the scenario you described.

Comment: have you tried using a HttpServletRequestWrapper? AFAIK, it would be difficult (or impossible) to reset the marker within the stream or reader objects. You could possibly extract the request, populate the wrapper object and pass it downstream. This is purely a theoretical concept; you might actually have to try it to see if it works.

Comment: No, is it a J2EE object?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the Servlet API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple answer is "No".

The stream is not resettable and there's no API method that will allow you to reopen it.  (And for good reason.  It would require the servlet infrastructure to keep a copy of the input *just in case* the servlet decided to reopen the stream.  That would be an unwarranted overhead.)

If you want to do this kind of thing, you will need to write your code to keep its own copy of the data.  If you are implementing this in a Filter (or a Tomcat Valve) then you could create a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to hide the fact that you've already read the data .... as suggested by @Vineet.

Answer (score 12):

Like other people have said, No I don't think there is a way to reset the request.

I have been in the same situation of wanting to log the content of the request in a ServletFilter before moving on.  Here is a [forum post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/361348/Servlets/java/Servlet-Filter-Reading-Request-Error) that helped me figure out how to create a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` like Stephen C was talking about.  That will store the data so you can call `getReader()` and `getInputStream()` multiple times.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private HttpServletRequest original;
    private byte[] reqBytes;
    private boolean firstTime = true;

    public MyRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        original = request;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException{

        if(firstTime)
            firstTime();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(reqBytes));
        return new BufferedReader(isr);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {

        if(firstTime)
            firstTime();

        ServletInputStream sis = new ServletInputStream() {
            private int i;

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                byte b;
                if(reqBytes.length > i)
                    b = reqBytes[i++];
                else
                    b = -1;

                return b;
            }
        };

        return sis;
    }

    private void firstTime() throws IOException{
        firstTime = false;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = original.getReader();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        reqBytes = buffer.toString().getBytes();
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution will cause problems with multipart requests. Don't know why exactly, but they no longer work.

Comment: Off hand, I'm not sure why multipart requests wouldn't work.  If you check out the link to the forum post from the answer, someone else has updated the code to fix an issue related to uploading files.  Couldn't hurt to look at what they changed to see if it also fixed multipart requests.

Comment: nice, I will check it out!