# Java filter input XML before controller

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, controller, inputstream, servlet-filters

I want to validate an XML received via http POST request to my Spring MVC Controller, but I need to validate it into a ServletFilter.

No problem to use DocumentBuilderFactory on the input stream: I parse and analyse the input correctly in my ServletFilter.

Passing over my filter, the debugger doesn't let me see what it happens in the various libraries and classes but I cannot land to the Spring Controller and I directly get "400 Bad Request" as response.

**Without** this line of code (and without all the subsequent parsing and validation of the xml file) **within my filter** :

```
Document doc = builder.parse(xml);
```

the request comes without any problems to the Spring Controller which maps the input XML to an Object called **RequestModel.java**

But when I add the parsing and validation in the filter, the navigation blocks before landing on the Controller, without throwing any Exception.

This is the snippet which makes me fail the call in my filter:

```
InputStream xml = request.getInputStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = builder.parse(xml); //ADDING THIS LINE IT FAILS!

        //method continues with  xml parsing and validation...
```

This is the beginning of my Controller method (with the parsing, the navigation gets blocked before):

```
@Controller
@EnableSwagger2
@RequestMapping("/listaprocessi")
@Api(description = "Lista processi ammessi", tags="Lista processi")
public class ListaProcessiController {

    @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ApiOperation(value="Lista processi")
    public BusinessListaProcessiModel listaProcessi(@RequestBody RequestModel requestModel) throws RemoteException{ ...}
```

Is it because to analise input the filter must wait until the stream closes? Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only process the ServletInputStream once.  So when you process it in your filter, it cannot be processed by the Spring MVC framework for your controller.

I have encountered this many times.  To fix this I wrap the HttpServletRequest in a new class (see below) that allows the InputStream to be reread.  If you wrap your HttpServletRequest in an instance of the class below and use it in your DocumentBuilder and pass it to your Filter's doFilter method, then you should be good.

```
public class CachingRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final String cachedMsgBody;

    public CachingRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws HttpErrorException {
        super(request);
        cachedMsgBody = ServletUtils.extractMsgBodyToString(request);
    }

    public CachingRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String msgBody) throws HttpErrorException {
        super(request);
        cachedMsgBody = msgBody;
    }

    public String getCachedMsgBody() {
        return cachedMsgBody;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedMsgBody.getBytes()));
        return new BufferedReader(isr);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        ServletInputStream sis = new ServletInputStream() {
            private int i = 0;
            byte[] msgBodyBytes = cachedMsgBody.getBytes();

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                byte b;
                if (msgBodyBytes.length > i) {
                    b = msgBodyBytes[i++];
                } else {
                    b = -1;
                }
                return b;
            }

            public boolean isFinished() {
                return i == msgBodyBytes.length;
            }

            public boolean isReady() {
                return true;
            }

            public void setReadListener(ReadListener rl) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        };

        return sis;
    }

}
```

Reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6322667/1490322