# how to get POST body from request during http exception handling?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot, microservices

I have 2 microservices. 1 of them sends a request to 2, 2 microservice throws an exception and adds new addition field *errors* to response with useful data:

```
    public static class ErrorResponse  {
        private Integer status;
        private String transactionId;
        private String sessionId;
        private String message;
        private List<FieldError> errors;
    //....setters/getters
    }

{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Validation failed for object='x'. Error count: 1",
    "sessionId": "",
    "transactionId": "xxx",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                ""
            ],
            "arguments": null,
            "defaultMessage": null,
            "objectName": "",
            "field": "",
            "rejectedValue": 0,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "invalid value"
        }
    ]
}
```

in 1 microservice I have a global exception handler which sends it on client, but the problem is that I can't get the filed *errors* from *HttpServletRequest*. getReader() method throws another exception. And as result client gets

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Validation failed for object='x'. Error count: 1",
    "sessionId": "",
    "transactionId": "xxx",
    "errors": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call getReader a second time. This link explains why: [resetting a HttpRequest after calling request.getReader()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322462/resetting-a-httprequest-after-calling-request-getreader). You can pass this information through a thread local if its something globally used through the application. You would need to make sure to reset the thread local appropriately. You could also catch the previous exception, wrap it in a custom exception class, and put this information inside of your custom exception. Then you can throw your custom exception that has the information you need.

Comment: thank you, but I know about that. I asked about the way to get data, or a way to throw an exception in 2 mkservice so that 1 can get the useful json data

Comment: please add the code where the exception is being thrown from. You could wrap the httpservletrequest and store the request body if nothing else would work.

Comment: it's throwed by standart @Valid annotation

Comment: if you are using spring mvc, please provide the code in the controller, if the request is making it there

Comment: bindingResult.rejectValue(secondFieldName, "Invalid value");  spring makes all others things

Comment: and I use feignClient to communications between them

Comment: Are you handling MethodArgumentNotValidException? This exception contain the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to implement ErrorDecoder interface and override

```
@Override
Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
    // response has getBody() method to get all data from a request 
}
```